# Issues using Pip to install Numpy/Pandas - Issue with Wheel

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pip

I have tried a bunch of different ways to try and get pip to install Numpy and Pandas, originally I was having issues with Jupyter Notebooks but I have gotten that fixed now.

I have tried to use different version on pip to install Numpy and Pandas but nothing seems to work. I keep getting the same error message, see below.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `Python 3.9. No luck with `numpy`, yet. Downgrade to 3.8

Comment: As an alternative to downgrading: You can download an unofficial Python 3.9 wheel for `numpy` from Christoph Gohlke's site https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.9 is pretty new, downgrade it to 3.8 as commented by Fourier. Issues with wheels can be fixed with:

```
pip install wheel
```